# how to take input from excel file and show output on speedometer

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am making an page through html5 and javascript. But i am  stuck in the middle of no where. In my page we have to take an excel file and read the whole data of it and show out put in the speedo meter..I dont know how to do that..

1. how to take input from excel file, or how to read excel file with javascript.
2. how to show output in speedometer, by that input which we have taken from that excel file ...

   ```
    <input type="button" value="Draw" onclick="drawWithInputValue();">
           <input type="file" id="file" onchange="checkfile(this);" />

     </div>
         </body>
              </html>
             <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                  function checkfile(sender) 
        {
     var validExts = new Array(".xlsx", ".xls", ".csv");
      var fileExt = sender.value;
       fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
      if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) 
   {
   alert("Invalid file selected, valid files are of " +
          validExts.toString() + " types.");
   return false;
   }
   else return true;

   }
   ```

   this is for the validation of the excel page .after that  i am totally confused
   i am here..Guys  please save me from this .  someone  please give me the logic for speedometer that can take input from excel and show output by rotating its stick

Comment: What have you done so far??
Excel file content have to be pushed in to database(use php,mysql) and then retrieve it back and then you can apply some js to it.

Comment: Show us your effort!!!what have you done so far??i mean where is your Nowhere...

Comment: speedometer is my problem fellas....how to provide an input to the speedometer and how to take output from it...thats the main problem

Comment: @user2502227:calm down,you seem to be new to stackoverflow. Re-edit your code.its humoungous.No body will read this much code. Post only the part that are causing you problem.Go to metaStackoverflow and read about how to ask question.Do some reasearch and again ask this question in a short,simpler way.This code wont get much attention because of its length

Comment: Rome wasn`t built in a day!!!
Go step by step.

1)learn about pushing excel data to database
2)How to retrieve it back from database.
3)send to javascript page using Json
4)how to retrieve json data
5)Based on data,how would you animate Speedometer?

Comment: If you want to read excel data from the browser itself, I have a library for that (demos http://niggler.github.io/js-xlsx/ and http://niggler.github.io/js-xls/ )

Comment: @Nirk thanx for your suggestion .but i have to take file from disk .that is done .but main problem is to show values via speedometer..

Comment: There are 3 steps: getting the file (HTML5 file api), reading the contents of the file (the aforementioned demos), and displaying the contents in a speedometer (you can use something like http://sindro.me/t/speedometer/speedometer.html)

Comment: thank you for your reply..you are going in right direction.. in same way i have to show value of excel file in speedometer..i had some code for speedometer i you say then i can supply you ,you should help me please...i am working on this since 3 days and i am going crazy....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can help you to read the excel file,

var xVal = 1;
var yVal = 2

```
function readdata(x,y) {
    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;
    try {
        var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        excel.Visible = false;
        var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\Test.xls");// alert(excel_file.worksheets.count);
        var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet1");
        var data = excel_sheet.Cells(x, y).Value;
        //alert(data);
        drawWithexcelValue(data);
        xVal = xVal + 1;
   }
    catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
   }
```